# Why WorkflowInvoker exception is not returning filename and line number in stacktrace

Tags: servicestack, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am using the WorkflowInvoker in my application. if any exception occurred, in StackTrace i am not getting the proper file name and line number.`do i need to include any logic?

```
        try
        {
            var outputs = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow, inputs);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Comment: Are the PDB's available with the assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `WorkflowApplication` and set its `OnUnhandledException` method to a delegate, like the following:

```
var wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(myWorkflow);
wfApp.OnUnhandledException = delegate(WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.UnhandledException.Message);
};
```